# Math.Clamp is not working in C# .NET (Windows Forms application)

Tags: c#, .net

Here is my line of code. You won't need any context for this line as the error is that Math does not have a definition for clamp.

Line:

```
priceChange = System.Math.Clamp(priceChange, minPriceChange, maxPriceChange);
```

> Error:    CS0117    'Math' does not contain a definition for 'Clamp'

I tried fixing it, but I can’t figure it out.

Comment: Are you running on .NET Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the provided parameters, the [`Math.Clamp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.clamp?view=net-7.0#system-math-clamp(system-int32-system-int32-system-int32)) have been available since .NET Core 2.0 (except for [`UIntPtr` and `IntPtr` overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.clamp?view=net-7.0#system-math-clamp(system-uintptr-system-uintptr-system-uintptr)) as far as I can see which are available since .NET 6):

| Product | Versions |
| --- | --- |
| .NET | Core 2.0, Core 2.1, Core 2.2, Core 3.0, Core 3.1, 5, 6, 7, 8 |
| .NET Standard | 2.1 |

If you running a .NET Framework project, it will not be available. But you can always copy [its implementation](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Math.cs,498).